# CakePHP list with SQL functions

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I would like generate list like day=>title:

```
$news = $this->News->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'News.created LIKE' => '2008-09%'),
    'fields' => array(
        'DAY(News.created) AS day',
        'News.name'),
    'recursive' => -1));
```

...but doesn't work, why?

Function SUBSTR/SUBSTRING also...

When I use find with 'all' property, the function DAY works good!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens and what do you expect to happen? You have to be more specific, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I know the question is already answered, but even "Generate incorrect list" is not really helpful. How should we know what "incorrect" is in this case? It is as useful as saying "does not work". You should provide an example of the list you get and the list you want. Keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work because `DAY(News.created)` is a computed value, but it will probably work if you make it a [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html).

Note that when you use `'all'`, each row on the results array will have a `[0][day]` key for that value, instead of `[News][day]`. This means Cake won't recognize it as a field from model `News`, and that's why you can't use it with `'list'`.